# Stop the pleonasm [mime-message]!

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

[MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) is used to refer to Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions.

[mime-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-message) as the name implies and its [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-message) refer to the same thing as [mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime).

Moreover, [mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime) has a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mime/info) while [mime-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-message) doesn't.

Since [mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime) is shorter and has far more questions while referring to the same thing, I would suggest to make [mime-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-message) a synonym of [mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime).

Even the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) agrees!

Comment: It seems to do its job just fine, the subject expert is Bill Shannon.  He works for Oracle and maintains JavaMail, answered many [mime-message] questions.  Sadly the tag got a case of the dash-disease, outbreaks are common at SO, it should be [mimemessage] to match the Java name.  Doesn't otherwise slow down questioners at all.  Or Bill.  Don't break what works, the principal job of a [tag] is to get the right subject experts connected to programmers that need their help.

Comment: @HansPassant You call it "dash-disease", I call it "separating words as such". "mimemessage" is not a word. In addition, I have trouble believing that having to follow four tags (rather than just one) doesn't "slow down questioners at all".

Comment: In hindsight bound to tick-off a dashing bright fellow, sorry.  [RTFM link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html)

Answer (score 3):

[mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime) could also refer to [mime-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-types). To make it easier to see the distinction [mime-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-mail) or [mime-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime-message) would be a better name IMHO. It's a sad state of affairs but people don't really read excerpts and will tag it with the first thing that looks roughly like what they want.

There's also [mail-mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mail-mime) by the way.

Comment: I'm wondering if we really need that level of granularity since the MIME rfcs define the MIME types as well. So maybe, [tag:mime-types] should also be a synonym of [tag:mime]. That would be like having a [tag:c-functions]